# Sign and Publish Maven Archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create some `archetypes` for my project [FlexFX](https://github.com/jtkb/flexfx) and I would like to build and publish these at the same as the main project itself. The issue I am facing is how to correctly structure the POMs so that the generated archetypes are signed and published and NOT the 'template project' from with they are created.

This is the module structure of the new `archetypes` module I am adding as a top level Maven project:

```
archetypes (POM.xml)
        |
        + multi-module (POM.xml)
               |
                + parent
                |
                + integration-test
                |
                + target
                        |
                        + generated-sources
                                |
                                + archetype (POM)
                                        |
                                        + target
                                                |
                                                + multi-module-archetype-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The module `multi-module` is the template from which I want to create the archetype so if I were to execute:

`mvn archetype:create-from-project`

I would end up with `multi-module-archetype-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` under the directory structure depicted above. However the `maven-gpg-plugin` module only signs the `multi-module` POM.xml and does navigate down into the `archetype` folder and sign that archetype JAR.

This is the `<build>` section of the `multi-module` POM:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.archetype.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>archetype-generation</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create-from-project</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also assume if I were to try and published the generated archetype i.e. to Maven Central it wouldn't happen although I have yet to confirm this. I assume it would need to be signed?

In summary the issues I am trying to resolve:

1. Configure Maven to sign the generated archetype jar.
2. Configure Maven to deploy the generated archetype jar.